# openni_tracker make fails with missing files

Tags: openi-tracker, openni-kinect, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

During rosmake of openni_kinect on OS X SL, openni_tracker fails complaining of missing files, like this:

```
/Users/john_muccigrosso/ros/openni_kinect/openni_tracker/src/openni_tracker.cpp:8:22: error: XnOpenNI.h: No such file or directory
```

There's a series of them, all beginning with Xn.

I've seen [this](http://kinect-with-ros.976505.n3.nabble.com/Ros-kinect-can-t-rosmake-most-of-the-openni-packages-td2515025.html), and I have geometry installed already. I have gotten openni_tracker to install in the past.

Thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9645/openni_tracker-make-fails-with-missing-files/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are from the OpenNI drivers.  Did you install them onto your system?  They are rosdeps of openni_kinect and need to be installed before compiling.  The drivers can be found [here](https://kforge.ros.org/project/openni/services/drivers/)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-04-09**:
OK. I have OpenNI drivers that, IIRC, I got as binaries from PrimeSense because I couldn't compile them on my OS X system. Where do I put them so that ros sees them? Or can I modify my rospath in some way to do that?